# Options to have a child but not giving birth

Tags: parents, pregnancy, adoption

My wife and I want to have a child, but my wife does not want to bear a baby.

We know we can adopt one from an orphanage. But what about child transferring from another family? Or bearing from another woman? Or any other options?

We are totally okay with the child not being completely biologically related to us.

If it depends on the country, we are in Australia.

Comment: And as far as legal questions are concerned: contact a lawyer, we are not equipped to answer this and hence at least that part is off topic here. See [help] for details.

Comment: This is probably a question better asked at city hall, they probably know what is allowed in your country and can help you with doing the paperwork (which is quite extensive)

Comment: No need to get angry -- it is a better question if it's on topic, and Parenting.SE simply isn't the place to speculate about legality. Whatever route you take to become a parent, a lawyer is often a component in non-biological approaches and it's appropriate for our community to let you know that consulting a lawyer is a useful next step. However, since you're clearly in the theoretical stages, we don't need to worry about the specific logistics of the possible methods yet, being letting you know they can be complicated and involve lawyers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 possible options...

1. Adoption. Not as easy as you might think, even if you adopt from overseas. It is typically very expensive, and takes years.
2. Surrogacy. Still very expensive, and a legal minefield.
3. Foster care. This would be the quickest, easiest (but still not easy) option. However this typically isn't a permanent arrangement. You might be caring for a child while the parents for various reasons are unable to.

Comment: Addition to the foster care portion: Adoption from foster care.  If you are willing to take an non-infant, this can be pretty quick, and not too expensive.  You can also do foster-to-adopt, where you care for foster kids, with the plan being to adopt them IF they do not return home.

Comment: Adoption from foster care unfortunately is relatively uncommon and difficult in Australia. Permanent removal of a child from his/her birth parents tends to only happen in the extreme circumstances.